# How to force the execution of a block of code in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In something like this, How can I force the execution of `@genre.Name` inside the string?

```
<a href="@Href("~/Store/Browse?genre=@genre.Name")">@genre.CommercialName</a>
```

In the HTML output I'm getting `<a href="Browse?genre=@genre.Name">` and I want someting like `<a href="Browse?genre=Rock">`.

Comment: Don't have properties that have side effects. It's an anti-pattern. Also, I don't think Razor does much in the way of caching values in templates. If you want real help, you might have to post more of your code (a whole loop or if, perhaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<a href="@Href("~/Store/Browse?genre=" + @genre.Name)">@genre.CommercialName</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
<a href="@Href("~/Store/Browse?genre=" + genre.Name)">@genre.CommercialName</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not Url.Action

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Browse", "Store", new { genre = genre.Name })">@genre.CommercialName</a>
```

put parameter in routeValues